# Windows 10 extremely slow after one of the latest updates

Tags: windows, performance, windows-10

A collegaue and I experience that our laptops have become extremely slow after one of the latest Windows 10 updates. Everything we do seems to stall a bit: Search in Visual Studio solution, open a file, open a new tab in Chrome, typing a bit fast in any kind of application, search for application in Windows, etc. The CPU, memory and disk usages are not anywhere near to 100 %. We both have a Asus Zenbook with the following stats:

**Processor:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz, 2401 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

**System Type:** x64-based PC

**Installed Physical Memory (RAM):** 10.0 GB

**System Model:** UX32VD

**Display Components:** GeForce GT 620M, NVIDIA compatible (Driver version: 358.50) &
 Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (Driver version: 10.18.10.4276)

**Disk:** Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series (See SSD Benchmark below)
[image: AS SSD Benchmark]

Windows Update history:

```
Node,Caption,CSName,Description,FixComments,HotFixID,InstallDate,InstalledBy,InstalledOn,Name,ServicePackInEffect,Status
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3074678,LAPTOP,Update,,KB3074678,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,8/18/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3074686,LAPTOP,Update,,KB3074686,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,8/18/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3081438,LAPTOP,Update,,KB3081438,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,8/18/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3081440,LAPTOP,Update,,KB3081440,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,8/18/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3081441,LAPTOP,Update,,KB3081441,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,8/21/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3081444,LAPTOP,Security Update,,KB3081444,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,8/21/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3081448,LAPTOP,Update,,KB3081448,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,9/14/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3081449,LAPTOP,Update,,KB3081449,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,9/14/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3081452,LAPTOP,Update,,KB3081452,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,8/28/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3081455,LAPTOP,Security Update,,KB3081455,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,9/14/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3087040,LAPTOP,Update,,KB3087040,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,10/7/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3097617,LAPTOP,Security Update,,KB3097617,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,10/21/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3099406,LAPTOP,Security Update,,KB3099406,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,10/19/2015,,,
LAPTOP,http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3105216,LAPTOP,Security Update,,KB3105216,,NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,10/21/2015,,,
```

It's just everything that has become slow.

Mine is upgraded from Windows 8.1, but my collegue's is a fresh install. But just to be clear: The computers have run fine with Windows 10 until recently.

Any ideas of what have gone wrong with the latest idea? Please tell me if you need more information about the computer and the Windows install.

**EDIT:** I have discovered, when the computer becomes slow, the CPU won't go above 41% on any of the cores.

Comment: How have you measured this performance drop exactly?

Comment: By looking at the screen and see everything stalling every time I do something. Search for something in Visual Studio, open a new tab in Chrome, typing a bit fast in any application, search for an application in Windows, open a file, etc. Thanks for pointing that out - I have described it in the question.

Comment: If you boot into a minimal boot configuration does it still happen?  What update(s) did you install precisely?  Have you done a benchmark on your SSD recently?  Do you have the current Nvidia drivers installed?  Do you have the recent Intel display drivers installed?

Comment: I have updated the question with answers to all your questions. I have booted with minimal boot configuration, but it does not make any difference. The Start menu in Windows is still slow. It was not possible to check all the scenarios since Windows could not load half of all my applications with minimal boot configurations.

Comment: try a linux live cd and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is very old but I just had the same problem and seem to have finally found a real solution.
My CPU was not clocking correctly and was stuck at under 1 GHZ so the performance was terrible.

Windows 10 seems to install a wrong version of the "Intel® Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Drive"
You can download and downgrade (!) the correct version directly from Asus (it is for Windows 8 but works perfectly even on Windows 10).

Asus Site:
http://www.asus.com/de/Notebooks/ASUS-ZenBook-UX32VD-II/HelpDesk_Download/

Switch to Windows 8 and look under Section "Others"

Direct Download Link: 
http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin8/DPTF/DPTF_Intel_Win8_64_Z6051080.zip

Hope this helps somebody also looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: You deserve a medal for this one. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue with exaclty the same device. I turned out to be some Windows energy-saving setting. Unfotunately, I can't tell you which one, but try to switch to the Maximum Power setting and see if the CPU goes over 40%. On my device it immediately went up to 80% and 2,79GHz.

Also I can recommend these steps:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3fm7m8/windows_10_is_very_laggy_and_slow_after_the_update/

Comment: Its better to post the essential parts from the referenced resource and then link back